# ClamAV's main.cld file is too large - can it be removed or compressed?

Tags: debian, clamav, disk-cleanup

The main.cld file in `/var/lib/clamav/` is over 400 MB in size and daily.cld is over 150 MB.

Are these filesizes normal and can these files be made smaller somehow? For example, by deleting them and retrieving them again, via some update or by using compression.

I'm using Debian11/KDE.

---

From [the docs](https://docs.clamav.net/appendix/Terminology.html?highlight=CLD):

> A CLD is the uncompressed ClamAV signature database archive. CLD files are created by FreshClam when a CVD or CLD database archive is updated with a CDIFF patch file.

Is moving it to another partition and creating a symbolic link the only way?

So far, I'm using that as a workaround, but people shouldn't be required to do this, especially not newcomers. I created the symbolic links like so (replace `dir` and `username`):

```
sudo mv /var/lib/clamav/main.cld /home/username/dir/main.cld
sudo mv /var/lib/clamav/daily.cld /home/username/dir/daily.cld
sudo ln -s /home/username/dir/daily.cld /var/lib/clamav/daily.cld
sudo ln -s /home/username/dir/main.cld /var/lib/clamav/main.cld
```